# Create deterministic graph with networkx

Tags: python, networkx

I've created a networkx static graph using the following code:

```
    G = nx.Graph()
    G.add_edges_from(edges)

    pos=nx.spring_layout(G)

    nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G,pos,node_size=6000, cmap="jet")
    nx.draw_networkx_labels(G, pos, labels, font_size=11)                    
    nx.draw_networkx_edges(G, pos, edge_color='b', alpha = 1, arrows=True)
    plt.show()
```

Running this multiple times on the same structure, I get different results (these results change every time I run it too):

[image]

I want to be able to use the same graph each time but only change the labels so I can see what is going on. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/reference/generated/networkx.drawing.layout.spring_layout.html), `nx.spring_layout` takes an optional `seed` argument which allows you to seed the underlying random number generator. Try:

```py
pos = nx.spring_layout(G, seed=1)
```